# How to use an array in json.net

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

How would I pass an array into `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`? I have the following working JSON but am unable to get it into the serialize function because it needs an array.

```
"recipients": [
    { 
        "address": "a@a.com" 
    },
    { 
        "address": "a@a.net" 
    },
    { 
        "address": "a@gmail.com" 
    }   
]
```

I'm new to c# and any help would be great, thanks!

C# body:

```
 recipients = new Array {

                }
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  It is missing outer braces -- `{` and `}`.  Is that a typo in the question?

Comment: You also haven't specified what your target structure looks like.  Also, I assume you've made a mistake and what you mean to say is you are trying to deserialize your json, not serialize it, since you haven't shown an origin C# object.

Comment: @dbc That's just a portion of my request.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C

Comment: https://github.com/fxstar/connectAPI/tree/master/Json

Comment: dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great way to create c# classes from JSON is http://json2csharp.com/. When I wrapped your JSON into curly braces as @dbc suggested and pasted there following code was generated:

```
public class Recipient
{
    public string address { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Recipient> recipients { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize it like this:

```
RootObject myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(myJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to build a valid Json object, Please refer to http://json.org/

For below model,

```
public class Model
{
    public string[] recipients { get; set; }
}
```

with below JsonDocument,

```
string jsondoc = "{\"recipients\": [\"a@a.com\",\"a@a.net\",\"a@gmail.com\"]}"
```

Below piece of code shoule be able to deserialize your json document

```
Model obj = new Model();
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsondoc)))
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Model));
    obj = (Model)deserializer.ReadObject(ms);
}
```